# Python requests - how to add multiple own certificates

Tags: python, ssl, urllib3

Is there a way to tell the requests lib to add multiple certificates like all .pem files from a specified folder?

```
import requests, glob
CERTIFICATES = glob('/certs/')
url = '127.0.0.1:8080'
requests.get(url, cert=CERTIFICATES)
```

Seems to work only for a single certificate

I already search google and the python doc. The best tutorial I found was [the SSL certification section in the official documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification).

Answer (score 5):

You can only pass in one certificate file at a time.

Either merge those files into one `.pem` file, or loop over the certificate files and try each one in turn until the connection succeeds.

A `.pem` file can hold multiple certificates; it should be safe to concatenate all your files together. See http://how2ssl.com/articles/working_with_pem_files/.