# Python requests with 2 ssl certificates

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I have two certificates that I need to use for a request in python.

I believe the syntax is like this:
r=requests.get('https://uat.xyz.com/xx', cert='1.cer')

But in my case there are two certificates that are needed. I tried to put them into a folder and did:
r=requests.get('https://uat.xyz.com/xx', verify='/certificates')

but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions what I can do to include multiple certificates?

Comment: SSL/TLS does not support two leaf certificates for the same connection. Or is this a leaf certificate and an intermediate certificate (to build the trust chain)?

Answer (score -1):

maybe its not the best solution, but you can ignore certificates:

```
 r=requests.get('https://uat.xyz.com/xx', verify=False)
```

after this script will throw warning(s) but it works

2nd solution with pem file:

[Python requests - how to add multiple own certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718360/python-requests-how-to-add-multiple-own-certificates/32718470)

```
r = requests.get('https://uat.xyz.com/xx', verify='/path/to/cetificate.pem')
```

Comment: The certificate is necessary as otherwise I don't get access

Comment: maybe like this: r=requests.get('https://uat.xyz.com/xx', cert=('1.cer', '2.cer'))

Comment: @JánosFarkas: this is the syntax for certificate key and value, not for two certificates. See http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

Comment: original post edited.