# How to use Python requests to connect to a server through proxy when both requires different client certificate

Tags: python-requests, python-3.6, http-proxy, ssl-client-authentication

I want to connect to a https server using python `requests` library through a proxy. The code roughly looks like

```
response = requests.get(SERVER_ENDPOINT, proxies=PROXIES, cert=??)
```

My problem is, both server and proxy requires client authentication, and unfortunately different CA is used to authenticate server and proxy. Is there a way to pass two CAs when making a request? The documentation doesn't seem to be very clear on this scenario.

Any help is greatly appreciated:)

**Method Tried:**

Tried the method as suggested in another link [Python requests - how to add multiple own certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718360/python-requests-how-to-add-multiple-own-certificates/32718470), and bundle certs and keys into separate pem files using the code below:

```
response = requests.get(SERVER_ENDPOINT, proxies=PROXIES, cert=(CERT_BUNDLE, KEY_BUNDLE))
```

It seems that only the 1st cert and key is used, so I am able to pass client auth at proxy server, but failed auth at destination server.

Comment: so you are asking how to send both certificate for server and for proxy itself ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python requests - how to add multiple own certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718360/python-requests-how-to-add-multiple-own-certificates)

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Tried but it doesn't work. I suspect it only took the first cert + key pair that works for proxy server, and uses the same pair for server auth, so I got status code 401 failed auth when talking to destination server.

Comment: loop over with try/except till connection success.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη It's a two step process,1) we need to pass client-auth at proxy server AND 2) pass client-auth at destination server, in one single request. I wonder how looping could possibly help in this scenario :(

Comment: I've no such materials to try it now. but i have the logic to apply

Comment: change the proxy to a caching only? I really don't understand why the config is complicated like that?